# Tweepy-Twitter Python : Get trends where no WOEID available

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

I've reading docs about twitter api's and I know how to get the trends for available countrys with Woeid (where on the world id).

Twitter has a list of countrys for which they can show the trends. When you list the availables places for trends you may notice that not all cities are supported.

My problem is that I need the trends for a country that has not support for its API. The country I need is El Salvador. This country has no support on the API, neither Woeid. But you can go to homepage and you will see the local trends to the right of window.

There is an option: get the latitude, longitude of El salvador and search trough twitter geo API for trends, but it will return you the trends for other country (Guatemala).

So, as far as I searched, using the api is not an option. Is there another way to get the twitter trends from El Salvador?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I’ve been doing what you need today.
Without being able to do an api call, which yahoo don’t support, go here;
https://www.yahoo.com/news/weather/el-salvador/apopa/apopa-76867

When you search a city, the woeid is added to the address bar.
Eg Apopa, El Salvador  is 76867

Type in city names in yahoo weather and get the ones you need.
Not the best solution but should work for what you need.